# 302 redirect (Redirect old domains all pages to new domains homepage)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

i want to redirect my old domains all pages to new domains homepage. for example; olddomain.com/article.html -> newdomain.com

My website is php based. How can i do this with htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

Here Redirect 301 does not work, as it redirects also to sub-directory.

This might work for you:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.olddomain\.com
RewriteRule ^ https://www.newdomain.com/ [R=301,L]
```